# VB If Else Statement not working in Combo box

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box for the selection of subjects according to semester. Like if first semester, then these will be the subjects and so on. My combo box is already populated that came from my database. My problem is, even it is First semester, the subjects shown on the combo box are the subject for the Second semester. I have this feeling that the error has nothing to do with my queries but in the condition itself.

```
Private Sub fillsubjectcombo()

    If yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" Or course_label.Text = "STEM" Or semester_label.Text = "Second semester" Then

        Dim str As String

        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 SS]"
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
        cmd.CommandText = str
        cmd.Connection = con
        drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

        While (drd.Read())

            subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 SS"))

        End While

        cmd.Dispose()
        drd.Close()
        con.Close()

    End If

    If yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" Or course_label.Text = "STEM" Or semester_label.Text = "First semester" Then

        Dim sti As String

        con.Close()
        con.Open()

        sti = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 FS]"
        cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sti, con)
        cmd.CommandText = sti
        cmd.Connection = con
        drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
        subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

        While (drd.Read())

            subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 FS"))

        End While

        cmd.Dispose()
        drd.Close()

        con.Close()

    End If
```

Can anyone help me? Please :(

Comment: I think you meant to use `And` instead of `Or` in your `If` statements.

Comment: I already tried using `And` but when I run the program, the combo box shows nothing.

Comment: Ok, you tried to change the 'Or' for an 'And' and it didn't work.But what's the real requirement, "Grade 11", "STEM" or "Second semester", or some of them, or all of them? You cannot just switch between 'and' and 'or' without meaning.

Comment: All of them sir @laancelot

Comment: Then I suggest that you use "AndAlso" as your operator. It's better than "And" in this case (in most cases) as it'll short-circuit if it's false. Then, put a breakpoint on this line and run the program. Put those conditions in the watch and see it it works as you think it does. Do you know how to do these things?

Comment: I tried using `AndAlso` as well. Whenever I use `And` or `AndAlso` in my condition, the combo box doesn't populate but when I use `Or` or `OrElse`, it populates.

Comment: The codes above is just the same as my another function for populating a combo box for teachers/professors. I just changed the queries and conditions and didn't encounter any problem in that at all.

Comment: I'm from another school system and not familiar with STEM and such, but the coder Vladut seems to think that "Grade 11" and "STEM" are the same thing and only one would be needed. If that's right, his parentheses would be spot on.

Comment: Now What I would like to know is which of these return false. That's why I'm speaking about breakpoints and debugging. Maybe there's a trailing space somewhere which makes the if statement false or something like that.

Comment: Grade 11 is for the year level of senior high school students while STEM is the strand/course of the student. I don't get the idea that they are the same thing. Also, there are 2 or 3 more strand/course for the year level of senior high school.

Comment: I see. I suspect there is something which makes your if statement return a boolean False, like a trailing space, or maybe a case problem. Do you need help with breakpoints and debug mode?

Comment: I tried what you said to use breakpoints. I put there all the conditions and all are returning true.

Comment: Have you been able to fill the combobox at any moment? If it's not the case, the line `subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 SS"))` in your while loop might be the problem. If your program enters the if condition, then the problem isn't the if condition but further down the line.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes the combo box is well populated.

Comment: You have a column in your database called STEM G11 SS. What is some sample data that is found in that column? BTW, what is the database you are using?

Comment: You are retrieving exactly the same data with both queries. It is only the order of the data that is different. I that what you intend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, when you copy and paste lines on the same page, think back on what you're doing, because it probably could be improved upon.

Here's a little thing I thought about your problem:

```
    If yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" AndAlso course_label.Text = "STEM" Then
        Dim query As String
        Dim className As String

        If semester_label.Text <> "" Then
            Select Case semester_label.Text
                Case "First semester"
                    className = "[STEM G11 FS]"
                    query = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY " & className
                Case "Second semester"
                    className = "[STEM G11 SS]"
                    query = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY " & className
            End Select

            con.Close()
            con.Open()

            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, con)
            cmd.CommandText = query
            cmd.Connection = con
            drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

            While (drd.Read())
                subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd(className))
            End While

            cmd.Dispose()
            drd.Close()
            con.Close()
        End If
    End If
```

Notice that it's almost exactly your code, but arranged in a way which avoid repetitions. And as a bonus, check your combo box now!

Comment: I liked your idea sir. A much cleaner look. I tried your code exactly and I'm having an error inside the while statement. 

Error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: [STEM G11 FS]

Comment: I got it sir. I removed the square brackets on the className and I just completed the query like `SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 FS]`

Comment: Good job! Did it fill your combo box with the right information?

Comment: Nope. I encountered another error here. I added another strand/course to my database. Let's say, ABM. Same codes applied but changed the queries and conditions to ABM. If ABM G11 First Sem, the subjects of STEM G11 First Sem are displayed in the combo box. If ABM G12 First Sem, nothing shows in the combo box. 

I'm crying rn T_T

Comment: I mean yes. It fills up right information IF strand/course is STEM.

Comment: I just added a failsafe in my code, because an empty string in `semester_label.Text` could cause unexpected results.

Comment: So ABM is an alternative to STEM? In the current code, only STEM is managed. If you wish to add a layer of choice you'll have to build it thoroughly. For an example, you could make a `Select Case course_label.Text` which would encapsulate both the STEM and the ABM possibilities.

Comment: No sir. STEM is like an engineering course while ABM is like an accountancy course.

Comment: Okay sir I managed to come up with your idea and it's working but I'm still left with one error. If ABM G12 First Sem or ABM G12 Second Sem, nothing shows in the combo box. I can't determine where's the error in my codes where I just copy pasted it with the STEM codes and just changed the conditions and queries.

Comment: I added another strand/course and it's called HUMSS, stands for Humanities and Social Sciences, together with its respective subjects in my database. Added it also to my select case statements and both HUMSS G11 and HUMSS G12 are working. I don't know what's the problem on ABM G12

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub fillsubjectcombo()

If (yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" Or course_label.Text = "STEM") AndAlso (semester_label.Text = "Second semester") Then

    Dim str As String

    con.Close()
    con.Open()

    str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 SS]"
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
    cmd.CommandText = str
    cmd.Connection = con
    drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

    While (drd.Read())

        subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 SS"))

    End While

ElseIf (yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" Or course_label.Text = "STEM") AndAlso (semester_label.Text = "First semester") Then

    Dim sti As String

    con.Close()
    con.Open()

    sti = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 FS]"
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sti, con)
    cmd.CommandText = sti
    cmd.Connection = con
    drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

    While (drd.Read())

        subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 FS"))

    End While

End If

cmd.Dispose()
drd.Close()
con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the way I understood your doubt is correct.

```
Private Sub fillsubjectcombo()

    If yearlabel.Text = "Grade 11" Or course_label.Text = "STEM" Then
        'use and instead of or if both condiions must be true
        If semester_label.Text = "Second semester" Then

            Dim str As String

            con.Close()
            con.Open()

            str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 SS]"
            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
            cmd.CommandText = str
            cmd.Connection = con
            drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

            While (drd.Read())

                subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 SS"))

            End While

            cmd.Dispose()
            drd.Close()
            con.Close()



        ElseIf semester_label.Text = "First semester" Then

            Dim sti As String

            con.Close()
            con.Open()

            sti = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 FS]"
            cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sti, con)
            cmd.CommandText = sti
            cmd.Connection = con
            drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

            While (drd.Read())

                subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd("STEM G11 FS"))

            End While

            cmd.Dispose()
            drd.Close()

            con.Close()
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you sir @laancelot with the codes you gave and I come up with this codes and it's all working!

Final codes are here where my problem in the If-Else statement has changed to Select-Case

```
If yearlabel.Text <> "" Then

        Select Case yearlabel.Text

            Case "Grade 11"

                If course_label.Text <> "" Then

                    Select Case course_label.Text

                        Case "STEM"

                            If semester_label.Text <> "" Then

                                Dim str As String
                                Dim classname As String

                                Select Case semester_label.Text

                                    Case "First Semester"
                                        classname = "STEM G11 FS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 FS]"

                                    Case "Second Semester"
                                        classname = "STEM G11 SS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G11 SS]"

                                End Select

                                con.Close()
                                con.Open()

                                cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
                                cmd.CommandText = str
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

                                While (drd.Read())
                                    subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd(classname))
                                End While

                                cmd.Dispose()
                                drd.Close()
                                con.Close()

                            End If

                        Case "HUMSS"

                            If semester_label.Text <> "" Then

                                Dim str As String
                                Dim classname As String

                                Select Case semester_label.Text

                                    Case "First Semester"
                                        classname = "HUMSS G11 FS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [HUMSS G11 FS]"

                                    Case "Second Semester"
                                        classname = "HUMSS G11 SS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [HUMSS G11 SS]"

                                End Select

                                con.Close()
                                con.Open()

                                cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
                                cmd.CommandText = str
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

                                While (drd.Read())
                                    subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd(classname))
                                End While

                                cmd.Dispose()
                                drd.Close()
                                con.Close()

                            End If

                    End Select

                End If

            Case "Grade 12"

                If course_label.Text <> "" Then

                    Select Case course_label.Text

                        Case "STEM"

                            If semester_label.Text <> "" Then

                                Dim str As String
                                Dim classname As String

                                Select Case semester_label.Text

                                    Case "First Semester"
                                        classname = "STEM G12 FS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G12 FS]"

                                    Case "Second Semester"
                                        classname = "STEM G12 SS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [STEM G12 SS]"

                                End Select

                                con.Close()
                                con.Open()

                                cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
                                cmd.CommandText = str
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

                                While (drd.Read())
                                    subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd(classname))
                                End While

                                cmd.Dispose()
                                drd.Close()
                                con.Close()

                            End If

                        Case "HUMSS"

                            If semester_label.Text <> "" Then

                                Dim str As String
                                Dim classname As String

                                Select Case semester_label.Text

                                    Case "First Semester"
                                        classname = "HUMSS G12 FS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [HUMSS G12 FS]"

                                    Case "Second Semester"
                                        classname = "HUMSS G12 SS"
                                        str = "SELECT* FROM [Subjects] ORDER BY [HUMSS G12 SS]"

                                End Select

                                con.Close()
                                con.Open()

                                cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(str, con)
                                cmd.CommandText = str
                                cmd.Connection = con
                                drd = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                subject_cbx.Items.Clear()

                                While (drd.Read())
                                    subject_cbx.Items.Add(drd(classname))
                                End While

                                cmd.Dispose()
                                drd.Close()
                                con.Close()

                            End If

                    End Select

                End If

        End Select

    End If
```

Again, thank you sir @laancelot!

Comment: Good Job! I took 10 minutes to optimize it a little bit, and left you comments through the code. Take a look : https://pastebin.com/PbrrKFv5

Comment: It's a bit long hahaha. Thank you for the effort! Gonna try that also.